# Inner join retornando linhas duplicadas

Tags: sql, mysqli, inner-join

tenho uma tabela ordem de compra, que se relaciona com a tabela produtos,
a tabela ordem de compra pode possuir vários produtos,

esta consulta
me retorna toda a ordem de compra, que possui mais de um produto, duplicada.

```
SELECT *   FROM unisis.ordem_de_compra
        inner JOIN unisis.oc_produtos
        ON ordem_de_compra.id = oc_produtos.id_ordem_de_compra 
        
          where oc_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()- INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE() and centro_custo = 'Balança'
```

o problema da consulta é que  exemplo(
se eu tenho uma Ordem de compra com 3 produtos cadastrados, ela me retorna da seguinte maneira

id:25 cliente: alberto  id_produto: 1 produto: a

id:25 cliente: alberto  id_produto: 2 produto: b

id:25 cliente: alberto  id_produto: 3 produto: c

gostaria que ela me retornasse da seguinte maneira

id:25 cliente: alberto

id_produto: 1 produto: a

id_produto: 2 produto: b

id_produto: 3 produto: c

Comment: Creio que ou falta algo ou tem algo demais na cláusula ON de sua junção.

Comment: O que você quer fazer com a consulta? O que a consulta está retornando? Tem mensagem de erro?

Comment: ON ordem_de_compra.id = oc_produtos.id_ordem_de_compra and ordem_de_compra.id essa linha está errada, faltou o resto depois do and

Comment: perdão realmente estava errada a consulta, arrumei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bancos de dados relacionais retornam conjunto de resultados (*resultsets*) que, por sua vez, têm *tuplas*, que são dados ordenados no que se convencionou chamar de *linhas* ou *registros*.

Todas as linhas têm coordenadas com origem e tipo definidos em tempo de compilação. Isto é, se eu escrever uma consulta SQL para trazer dados de uma tabela, é exatamente essa consulta que me diz quais são os tipos de dados de cada coordenada e quais são as colunas de onde os dados vêm.

```
--Tabela students(id PK, firstName string)

SELECT firstName, COUNT(firstName)
FROM students
GROUP BY firstName
```

Na consulta acima, temos duas coordenadas por tupla: `firstName`, que é uma coluna da tabela `students`, e `COUNT(firstName)` que, em última análise, é um valor inteiro que depende se `firstName` é NULL ou não.

Dessa forma, ***não** há* como uma consulta SQL retornar tuplas de tipos e origem diferentes dependendo da linha.

Entretanto, dependendo do SGBD, você pode obter mais de um conjunto de resultados sob uma mesma sessão. Procure por `more than one resultset`, `mysql` no seu buscador preferido para obter mais detalhes.

Comment: obrigado atendeu minha necessidade

Comment: Favor marcar a minha resposta como melhor resposta.